# Comportamiento Exepciones en un hilo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una AppWeb montada en el IIS de un servidor. Esta app hace envios de mail constantes. Para cada envio de mail se crea un hilo de forma que se pueda seguir navegando por la app sin tener que esperar a que se mande el mail
Este mail muchas veces puede fallar en el envio. Con lo cual se genera una exepcion. Hay algun problema si catcheo pero no lanzo la exepcion? Es decir no me interesa hacer nada con la exepcion, simplemente que la app siga su flujo normal.

Comment: ninguno.. tuviste algun problema? bah, salvo que nadie se va a enterar que el mail no se envio

Comment: Para situaciones así tienes varias opciones, puedes crear un proyecto con MSMQ, RabbitMQ para encolar los envíos de correo electrónico, puedes tener un servicio de windows que se encargue de ello donde si saltó una excepción, revisar los que hayan tenido errores e intenten de nuevo. Considera lo que dice el buen @gbianchi Es importante conocer si el correo se envió satisfactoriamente o no.

Comment: Cuando catcheo la exepcion lo guardo en un Log, por ende llevo un regitro de que mail se mando y cual no. Pero la duda venia mas que nada si al estar en un hilo y no lanzar la exepcion podia pasar algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pasa nada, puedes atrapar el exception y solo loguearlo ya que no estas esperando una respuesta de esa tarea que lanzas en un thread como para tener que cotinuar con otra accion

Si las task aunque sean asincronas dependen para que ejecute otras, en ese caso la exception deberia ser tratada de forma diferente

Podrias usar

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 

   try
   {
       DoSomething();
   } catch (Exception ex){
     //aqui logueas
   }

});
```

Pero ojo que el log no puede fallar porque sino tendrias un exception que si va a escalar

[How to Use Multi-Threading With Tasks in C#](https://www.thoughtco.com/multi-threading-in-c-with-tasks-958372)

Otra forma seria usando

```
var task = Task.Run(() => EnvioMail())
           .ContinueWith(failedTask => HandleError(failedTask), 
                         TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

solo ingresara el continue si falla, por eso el `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`, lo explica mejor en

[Exception handling (Task Parallel Library)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library)

busca el titulo `Observing exceptions by using the Task.Exception property`